# 404 Bad Request error Spring Boot for Open Api

Tags: spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

```
@Service
public class AirService {

    @Value("${api.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    @Value("${api.url}")
    private String apiUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

   Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AirService.class);

    public double fetchTotalPrice() {
        logger.info("Fetching total price from Air France API...");

        httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/hal+json");
        httpHeaders.set("API-Key", "apiKey");
        httpHeaders.set("AFKL-TRAVEL-Host", "KL");

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);

        logger.info("Sending request to  API: {}", apiUrl);
        logger.info("Request body: {}", httpHeaders);


        try {
            ResponseEntity<FlightResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, FlightResponse.class);

            logger.info("Received response from API: {}", responseEntity);
            logger.info("Response status code: {}", responseEntity.getStatusCode());

            if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                FlightResponse ApiResponse = responseEntity.getBody();

                double totalPrice = airFranceApiResponse
                        .getDestinationCities()
                        .get(0)
                        .getFlightProducts()
                        .get(0)
                        .getPrice()
                        .getTotalPrice();
                logger.info("Total price retrieved: {}", totalPrice);
                return totalPrice;
            } else {
                logger.error("Error fetching total price: {}", responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
                return 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unexpected error occurred", e);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

error message:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : "{"errors":[{"code":2000,"name":"OFA/TECHNICAL/CLIENT_ERROR","description":"Unreadable message"}]}" I am trying to fetching data from open Api, I am sure the headers.I use same request for Postman and it works but I couldn't implement truley spring boot.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message because I forgot to include the request body when moving from api client to code (Bruno -> Bun/Svelte/Wretch).

I don't know Java or Spring Boot, but my guess would be that the request body is missing or malformed. Have you tried using `Content-Type: application/json`? The AFKLM api responds with `application/hal+json`, but I'm not aware of any endpoints that expect it.